# Why error 'invalid object name' if tables are from same server different databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

With the query below I'm trying to join both tables :

```
select  
    a1.member_account,
    substring(substring(a1.member_name, charindex('/', a1.member_name)  + 1, len(a1.member_name)), 0, charindex(' ', substring(a1.member_name, charindex('/', a1.member_name) + 1, len(a1.member_name)))) as firstname, 
    substring(a1.member_name, 0, charindex('/', a1.member_name)) as lastname,
    a2.account, a2.PriorMonthRewardAmount,
    a2.CurrentMonthRewardAmount, a2.RewardDate, a2.RedemptionAmount, 
    a2.RedemptionDate, a1.member_email, 
    a1.member_rest_flag11, a1.member_rest_flag12
from 
    [NFCUDW].[dbo].[member] as a1
left join 
    [IMS].[dbo].[RewardsHistory] as a2 on a2.account = a1.member_account 
order by 
    DATEPART(year, a2.rewarddate) desc,
    DATEPART(month, a2.rewarddate) desc
```

These two tables are in the same server but different databases and I'm trying to join them.

I get error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'IMS.dbo.RewardsHistory'.

I have access to both tables, so I don't understand why I get this error.

What I tried to do at first was join these two queries:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    RewardsHistory
where 
    priormonthrewardamount > 0
order by 
    DATEPART(year, rewarddate) desc,
    DATEPART(month, rewarddate) desc 

select  
    member_account,
    substring(substring(member_name, charindex('/', member_name) + 1, len(member_name)), 0, charindex(' ', substring(member_name, charindex('/', member_name) + 1, len(member_name)))) as firstname, 
    substring(member_name, 0, charindex('/', member_name)) as lastname,
    member_email, member_rest_flag11, member_rest_flag12
from 
    member
```

Comment: Maybe this link will help: http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/joining-tables-different-databases

Comment: does select * from ims.dbo.[rewardshistory] give results?

Comment: @twelfth yes it gives me all the table records

Comment: Are you using case sensitive collation on objects?  If yes, do you have the case correct on the three part name??

Comment: Well, that shouldn't be.  Kill the [] for a minute....does this give results?  :    select top 5 * from NFCUDW.dbo.[member] as a1 left join IMS.dbo.[RewardsHistory] as a2

Comment: @twelfth i removed the [] and still same error

Comment: Have you tried calling it from one schema or the other?  As in select ... from member left join [IMS].[dbo].[RewardsHistory]

Comment: just tried running rewardshistory on the other schema and it gave me same error

Comment: i have decided to do this a complete different way , thanks

Answer (score -1):

I could be totally wrong here, just a shot in the dark, but the part of your query where you declare the alias

```
as lastname,a2.account, a2.PriorMonthRewardAmount,
   a2.CurrentMonthRewardAmount,a2.RewardDate,a2.RedemptionAmount,a2.RedemptionDate,
   a1.member_email,a1.member_rest_flag11,a1.member_rest_flag12
```

seems like it would cause problems.  It certainly looks confusing, but aren't alias supposed to be a single term or quoted string?  You've included a whole list.

Comment: there is a , after `lastname`, which means its a new column

Comment: THats in his select clause and he is aliasing "substring(a1.member_name,0,charindex('/',a1.member_name))" as last name as he should

Comment: Sorry, missed the comma after `lastname`.  Like I said, a shot in the dark.